# How to convert the normal html checkboxes syntax to spring form:checkboxes

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc, checkbox

I have this

```
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="var1" varStatus="counter">
<input type="checkbox" name="passports[${counter.index}].country_issue" value="${var1.country_name}" >${var1.country_name}</input>
    </c:forEach>
```

Now i want to convert it to something like

```
<form:checkboxes path="passports[${counter.index}].country_issue"
```

The problem here is that how will i use varStatus here for counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need it I guess, would this not work?:

```
<form:checkboxes path="passports.country" items="${countryList}" />
```

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve; you're using the index of one list (countries) as the index for another list (passports)?

If for some reason you do need the varStatus then you'll need to use form/checkbox instead.

regards,
Stijn

Comment: i tried that and it says invalid property passports.country_issue. because passports is a List collection , not single object

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly you will show a list of countries and for each country there is a checkbox to set whether or not passport for that country is true or not. The way I would set this up is by creating a class CountryView with as properties String countryName and boolean passport (and other properties if required). Then you simply 'send' a list of countryViews to the jsp and use <form:checkboxes items="${countryViewsList}" path="passport" value="countryName" />